# Liferay: amd-loader error, require() call has failed

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, osgi, osgi-bundle

After a server restart the frontend app started throwing some errors and can't find any document that is useful for this issue.

These errors were thrown in the console as javascript errors

```
liferay-amd-loader | A require() call has failed but no failure handler was provided. Note that even if the call stack of this error trace looks like coming from the Liferay AMD Loader, it is not an error in the Loader what has caused it, but an error caused by the require() call. The reason why the Loader is in the stack trace is because it is printing the error so that it doesn't get lost.However, we recommend providing a failure handler in all require() calls to be able to recover from errors better and to avoid the appearance of this message.
```

Some information about the require() call follows:
· Require call id: 0
· Required modules:

```
[
"portal-template-react-renderer-impl@4.0.7/render.es",
"product-navigation-applications-menu@1.0.2/js/ApplicationsMenu",
"metal-dom/src/all/dom",
"portal-template-react-renderer-impl@4.0.7/render.es",
"frontend-taglib-clay@5.0.3/DropdownMenu"
]

 Error: Load timeout for modules: portal-template-react-renderer-impl@4.0.7/render.es,product-navigation-applications-menu@1.0.2/js/ApplicationsMenu,metal-dom/src/all/dom,portal-template-react-renderer-impl@4.0.7/render.es,frontend-taglib-clay@5.0.3/DropdownMenu
at combo?browserId=chrome&minifierType=js&languageId=en_US&b=7304&t=1637093660756&/o/frontend-js-aui-web/aui/widget-stdmod/widget-stdmod.js&/o/frontend-js-aui-web/aui/aui-aria/aui-aria.js&/o/frontend-js-aui-web/aui/aui-io-plugin-deprecated/aui-io-plugin-deprecated.js&/o/frontend-js-aui-web/aui/aui-io-request/aui-io-request.js&/o/frontend-js-aui-web/aui/aui-loading-mask-deprecated/aui-loading-mask-deprecated.js&/o/frontend-js-aui-web/aui/aui-overlay-base-deprecated/aui-overlay-base-deprecated.js&/o/frontend-js-aui-web/aui/aui-overlay-context-deprecated/aui-overlay-context-deprecated.js&/o/frontend-js-aui-web/aui/aui-overlay-manager-deprecated/aui-overlay-manager-deprecated.js&/o/frontend-js-aui-web/aui/aui-overlay-mask-deprecated/aui-overlay-mask-deprecated.js&/o/frontend-js-aui-web/aui/aui-parse-content/aui-parse-content.js&/o/frontend-js-aui-web/liferay/session.js&/o/frontend-js-aui-web/liferay/deprecated.js&/o/frontend-js-web/loader/config.js&/o/frontend-js-web/loader/loader.js&/o/frontend-js-web/misc/svg4everybody.js&/o/frontend-js-web/liferay/dom_task_runner.js&/o/frontend-js-web/liferay/events.js&/o/frontend-js-web/liferay/lazy_load.js&/o/frontend-js-web/liferay/liferay.js&/o/frontend-js-web/liferay/global.bundle.js&/o/frontend-js-web/liferay/portlet.js&/o/frontend-js-web/liferay/workflow.js:146:489
```

I'm using Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.3.4 CE GA5 and the site was working before the restart, so I assume I left out one step or something.
Did anyone else ran into this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask]: _Just_ the error message without steps to reproduce doesn't really provide good basis to help you fix the problem.

Comment: You're mentioning _"the frontend app"_: Is that your custom code? Please provide a [mcve] (and thank you for replacing the image with text)

Answer (score 0):

There is a timeout mentioned in the error message. You can increase the timeout in Control Panel > System Settings > Infrastructure > JavaScript Loader > Module Definition Timeout. It is 7 seconds by default. But it would be better to reduce the size of your javascript app.